# Pandas: trying to keep max row for a particular market

Tags: pandas

In below code, For each dates_marker, if holiday column is list, I would like keep single holiday in the holiday column. The logic, I am trying to implement is to keep the holiday where avg(tickets_sold) is max, if there is tie then use avg(revenue) if still a tie is there then take the first holiday in the list. But, it is not working. I have exploded holiday, not I have single holiday entry per row, then created reference_data which need to be used to only keep max entry for each date_marker

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'holiday': [["King's Birthday", "Father's Day", "Charles Day"], ["King's Birthday", "Father's Day"], 
                ["New Year's Day", "Father's Day"], ["New Year's Day", "Father's Day"], 
                ['Christmas', 'Boxing Day'], ['Christmas', 'Boxing Day'], 
                ['Christmas', 'Boxing Day'], ['Christmas', 'Boxing Day'], 
                "New Year's Day", "New Year's Day", "New Year's Day", "New Year's Day", 
                'Easter', 'Easter', 'Easter', 'Easter'],
    'tickets_sold': [167, 168, 1, 2, 356, 357, 358, 359, 92, 93, 105, 106, 97, 98, 89, 90],
    'revenue': [12, 12, 44, 33, 21, 212, 12, 12, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024],
    'dates_marker': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.explode('holiday')

reference_data = df.groupby('holiday').agg({'tickets_sold': np.mean, 'revenue': np.mean})
```

Comment: Each dates_marker only has one ticket sales and one revenue. How do you want to keep the max entry for each dates_marker?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the average revenue and average tickets columns to `df`
2. `sort_values` in the priority order
3. `drop_duplicates` and `drop` unnecessary columns

```
df["tickets_avg"] = df.groupby("holiday")["tickets_sold"].transform("mean")
df["revenue_avg"] = df.groupby("holiday")["revenue"].transform("mean")

output = (df
          .sort_values(["dates_marker","tickets_avg","revenue_avg"], ascending=[True,False,False])
          .drop_duplicates(subset="dates_marker")
          .drop(columns=["tickets_avg","revenue_avg"])
          )

>>> output 
            holiday  tickets_sold  revenue  dates_marker
0   King's Birthday           167       12             1
1   King's Birthday           168       12             2
2      Father's Day             1       44             3
3      Father's Day             2       33             4
4         Christmas           356       21             5
5         Christmas           357      212             6
6         Christmas           358       12             7
7         Christmas           359       12             8
8    New Year's Day            92     2021             9
9    New Year's Day            93     2021            10
10   New Year's Day           105     2022            11
11   New Year's Day           106     2022            12
12           Easter            97     2023            13
13           Easter            98     2023            14
14           Easter            89     2024            15
15           Easter            90     2024            16
```